# Finding a prime in range with the largest minimal non quadratic residue

Tags: finite-fields, quadratic-residues, quadratic-reciprocity

Given k, I'm trying to find the k-bit prime that has the largest minimal non-quadratic residue.

I was wondering if there's any construction like that. Perhaps some use of the CRT?

Comment: Sounds tough. At least because just listing all $k$ bit primes is taxing for larger $k$. For moderate size $k$ I would start by simply sieving out those primes that have $2,3,5,\ldots,$ as QRs, because quadratic reciprocity makes that easy.